# how to capture relative path using capybara after click event

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to capture complete url_path using capybara esp after you made some changes in the page and those reflect in the URL.

Initially the URL - "/mysite.com/nnn"
When I click on page 10 the updated URL would be -- "/mysite.com/nnn/page_10"

when I tried "current_url" the result is "/111.0.0.1:61867/mysite.com/nnn"

expected result: "/111.0.0.1:61867/mysite.com/nnn/page_10"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'd suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It'll help you write good questions and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform actions on the page using Capybara, those actions are often not complete (click link, etc) immediately, so looking at current_url immediately won't necessarily reflect what it will be in a few seconds once the action has completed.  In Capybara 2.5 you can use the has_current_path matcher to make it retry until the path changes to what you expect

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("/mysite.com/nnn/page_10")
```

or if you really want to check the whole url instead of just the path

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("/111.0.0.1:61867/mysite.com/nnn/page_10", url: true)
```